# which device file is for pci device

Tags: linux, device, pci

Lots of Linux book said that "everything is a file", they also said that "you can treat I/O device as a spcial file/device file."

1. For HDA device, of cource I can find /dev/hda device file for it. However for PCI device, for example the graphic card, which device file is for it?
2. We can devide devices into two types : char and block. Then what type is the graphic card?

Answer (score 0):

If "Everything is a file" is true than check for open files.
Lets say `vlc` is streaming a video it should connect to `/dev/` in some way...

```
$ lsof | grep vlc | grep /dev/
```

...that print out many /dev/ lines but one makes curious...

```
/dev/dri/card0
```

...so take a look on it...

```
$ ls -la /dev/dri/card0
crw-rw---T 1 root video 226, 0 Nov 30 13:59 /dev/dri/card0
```

What device is useable in /dev/ strongly depends on what modules are loaded.
( lsmod )
And of course on hardware.
( lspci )